# Getting all global filters programatically of an ASP MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a snippet that maps all ASP MVC routes to create a menu structure, so far I've found good snippets that allow me to retrieve a list of ActionResults and their attributes.

As a last requirement I want to validate if the ActionResult requires Authentication. Since I can validate if the controller or the action itself has the Authorized attribute I've got that case covered, but when I register the Authorization attribute globally I can't get that.

Is there a way to get all the global Filters registered?

Here is the code for my snippet so far:

```
public static class MvcApplicationHelpers
{
    public static List<MvcApplicationRoute> MapMvcApplicationRoutes(Type mvcApplicationType, ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames applicationActionReturnType = ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames.ActionResult)
    {
        var mvcAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(mvcApplicationType);

        var assemblyProjectName = mvcAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0];

        return mvcAssembly.GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(x => x.ReturnType.Name == applicationActionReturnType.ToString())
            .Select(x => new MvcApplicationRoute
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller", ""),
                Action = x.Name,
                ReturnTypeName = x.ReturnType.Name,
                Area = x.DeclaringType.Namespace.ReplaceMany(assemblyProjectName,"Area",".Controllers","Controllers"),
                Attributes = string.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))),
                ControllerAttributes = string.Join(",", x.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))),
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public static List<MvcApplicationNavigationRoute> MapMvcApplicationNavigationRoutes(Type mvcApplicationType, ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames applicationActionReturnType = ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames.ActionResult)
    {
        var mvcApplicationRoutes = MapMvcApplicationRoutes(mvcApplicationType, applicationActionReturnType);

        return mvcApplicationRoutes
            .Where(c => c.ReturnTypeName == ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames.ActionResult.ToString())
            .GroupBy(c => new
            {
                c.Action,
                c.Area,
                c.Controller,
                c.ControllerAttributes,
                c.Attributes
            })
            .Select(c => new MvcApplicationNavigationRoute
            {
                Action = c.Key.Action,
                Area = c.Key.Area,
                Controller = c.Key.Controller,
                RequiresAuthorization = ValidateAuthorizationRequiredAttributes(c.Key.Attributes, c.Key.ControllerAttributes),
            })
            .ToList();

    }

    private static bool ValidateAuthorizationRequiredAttributes(string attributes, string controllerAttributes)
    {
        string authorizedAttributeName = "Authorize";
        if(attributes.Contains(authorizedAttributeName) || controllerAttributes.Contains(authorizedAttributeName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public enum ApplicationActionReturnTypeNames
{
    ActionResult,
    PartialViewResult,
    FileResult
}

public class MvcApplicationRoute
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string ReturnTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Attributes { get; set; }
    public string ControllerAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class MvcApplicationNavigationRoute
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresAuthorization { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresPermission { get; set; }
    public string[] AllowedRoles { get; set; }
    public string NavigationName { get; set; }
    public bool SpecialAccess { get; set; }
    public string Permission { get; set; }
    public string PermissionAction { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As a last requirement I want to validate if the ActionResult requires
>   Authentication.

I am not sure if I have understood your requirement but what you are doing sounds non-standard to me.

If you have added `[Authorize]` attribute globally, then all your action methods will be authorizes by default. If you don't want to Authorize certain action method, add `[AllowAnonymous]` to it.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // Since you have globally registered [Authorize], this would be automatically Authorized
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // some code... 
    }

    [AllowAnonymous] // <-- do not authorize this action
    public ActionResult NoAuthorizeAction()
    {
        // some code... 
    }
}
```

Validation is whole difference thing, it is normally done on your model... You can add built in validation attributes such as `[Required]` or `[Range]` to your model... you can define your own [Custom Validation Attribute](http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-do-custom-validation-using-validationattribute-of-aspnet-mvc.aspx), or your model can implement [IValidatableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netframework-4.8). All of these validation will be executed  on your model and you can check if the model state is valid in your controller...

I am not sure why do you want to validate Authorization attribute?

Comment: What I want is a code that could be implemented on any MVC application that using reflection or any other mean will allow me to get the navigation routes and stablish which controller routes need authenticated access or not and map the navigation structure (like to generate a Sitemap por example)